# Scipy's optimize.minimize outputs message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.' How to get the best result despite this

Tags: python, math, optimization, scipy, ads

I get a message that reads 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'

Why exactly does that happen and How do I find out what the true ideal result is?

I found better results by iterating different starting values with nested for-loops. But I don't think my nested for-loops will hit a better value than the one where it returns

```
sucess:True
```

Here is a short version of my code:

```
def func (coefficients):
a_coef, b_coef, c_coef, d_coef, e_coef = coefficients
#This is a sum equation that I stitched together, I'll add a screenshot of the actual equation below, in case it helps anyone
return (((a_cost+d_cost)*icpa*a_adj*a_coef*d_adj*d_coef)-(a_conv+d_conv))**2+(((a_cost+e_cost)*icpa*a_adj*a_coef*e_adj*e_coef)-(a_conv+e_conv))**2+(((b_cost+d_cost)*icpa*b_adj*b_coef*d_adj*d_coef)-(b_conv+d_conv))**2+(((b_cost+e_cost)*icpa*b_adj*b_coef*e_adj*e_coef)-(b_conv+e_conv))**2+(((c_cost+d_cost)*icpa*c_adj*c_coef*d_adj*d_coef)-(c_conv+d_conv))**2+(((c_cost+e_cost)*icpa*c_adj*c_coef*e_adj*e_coef)-(c_conv+e_conv))**2
    result = optimize.minimize(func, (1.2,1.2,1,0.6,1.2))
    print(result)
```

This is my output:

```
fun: 20773.023398686084
 hess_inv: array([[ 2.21447705e-05,  2.33193163e-05,  1.49303033e-05,
        -1.24123199e-05, -3.18490802e-05],
       [ 2.33193163e-05,  2.56532976e-05,  1.60651145e-05,
        -1.33677287e-05, -3.39619186e-05],
       [ 1.49303033e-05,  1.60651145e-05,  1.03618906e-05,
        -8.50741092e-06, -2.18606606e-05],
       [-1.24123199e-05, -1.33677287e-05, -8.50741092e-06,
         7.07829337e-06,  1.80616076e-05],
       [-3.18490802e-05, -3.39619186e-05, -2.18606606e-05,
         1.80616076e-05,  4.92572403e-05]])
      jac: array([0.02050781, 0.02294922, 0.04882812, 0.16308594, 0.00244141])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 323
      nit: 16
     njev: 52
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([1.49116998, 1.53997584, 1.06245875, 0.88491235, 2.15146809])
```

It might be worth mentioning, that my mathematical understanding doesn't suffice to understand what is happening in the background. For instance when I try the Nelder-Mead method, I get a success but the the result is still larger than the result of a failed attempt with the default method.

[Screenshot of the aforementioned equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNBYc.png)

Comment: I think your objective function is taking large values (in absolutes) compared to your numerical tolerance set by gtol. Try increasing gtol and see which value silences the message, see if this value is suitable to you. Otherwise you could scale down the objective value (by finding a natural normalization factor for it).